# Extracting text in excel cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel column something like

```
    900sft
    1000sft
    1050sft
    1050sft
    3000sft
    217 sqyd
    267sqyd
    235sqyd
    186sqyd
    250sqyd
    1610 sft
```

Now I want to extract the digits to the next cell and the text to another. I managed to get the numbers by doing this:

=1*MID(raw!E2,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(raw!E2,ROW($1:$9),1)),0),COUNT(1*MID(raw!E2,ROW($1:$9),1)))

-- raw!E2 is the source cell
-- first record shows 900

don't know how to separate the text.. any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is best approached via VBA. A simple `IsNumeral` check of True or False in a function can do this no problem. Possible issue is decimal points, which can be dealt with via `RegEx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that the 900 is in cell F2. You can simply use something like this:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(raw!E2,F2,""))
```